# Minimum value of prefix sum of array with integer values

Tags: data-structures, logic

Given an array like [3,4,6,1,1]. Arrange it in such a way that it's prefix sum gives minimum value for the expression given below. prefix sum array will be
[3,7,13,14,15]
We have to calculate it's value like
3-7+13-14+15=10  so arrange the original array in such a way that this value is minimized

Comment: When you are asking for an algorithm that could solve this, you could just simply apply a brute-force algorithm, which tries every combination of orderings, resulting in O(n!). But if you want this in a more sophisticated way, I would recommend you to try a dynamic programming approach.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a hint.

Let's suppose the output array is of the form: `[p1, p2, ... pn]`. In your example, the 5-element output array is of the form: `[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]`. Then the resulting expression value is:

```
+p1
-p1-p2
+p1+p2+p3
-p1-p2-p3-p4
+p1+p2+p3+p4+p5
```

which is: `+p1+p3+p5`. Now you only have to minimize this sum, which you can easily do for example by sorting the input array and selecting the 3 smallest elements and placing them at positions `1`, `3` and `5`. The remaining elements and the ordering do not matter.

If the input array is of even length, you do it in a similar way. For example (length=4):

```
+p1
-p1-p2
+p1+p2+p3
-p1-p2-p3-p4
```

Result: `-p2-p4`. So here you have to select the 2 biggest elements and place them at positions `2` and `4`.

Does this make sense? Do you know how to code this in the general case?